# Cycles, Shadeless Materials, and Baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking

To decrease render times in Cycles, I have baked a number of textures. I then display the baked textures using a "shadeless node group" like this:

[image]

It works great. The scene renders very quickly:

[image]

I have now added a perfectly reflective sphere to the scene, and I want to bake the reflection of the scene on the surface of the sphere. But when I do so, I get this:

[image]

That makes sense, because I use the "Is Camera Ray" filter on the "Light Path" node when creating my shadeless node group. But I'm not sure how to fix that group to work with baking (as opposed to full-scene rendering). There is no "Is Bake Ray" option in the Light Path node.

Thanks for your help!